# How can I change the mouse cursor theme in raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

I have installed an windows 8-style cursor theme for openbox, as that is the default raspbian gui(I think)and used it with xfce which I installed on raspbian. I can't find a mouse configuration tool where I can change the theme. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xfce mouse configuration tool is `xfce4-mouse-settings`. I don't have any Debian based distribution at hand but it should be installed with `aptitude install xfce4-mouse-settings`. You can substitute `aptitude` with `apt-get` if the former is not installed with Raspbian.

Also note that you can install a new cursor theme by unpacking the archive (generally a ZIP file) into `$HOME/.icons`, i.e. the `.icons` subdirectory of your user profile's directory. It is a hidden directory, as indicated by the leading period. To change your current cursor theme manually, edit (or create) this file:

```
$HOME/.icons/default/index.theme
```

with the following content:

```
[icon theme] 
Inherits=<theme-name>
```

Just don't be fooled by the term "icon". However this will create a hard "link" to the default cursor theme, which may interfere with the cursor theme settings in `xfce4-mouse-settings`.

(Graciously copied from [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cursor_themes).)