# How to to change the cursor theme using terminal/cli?

Tags: raspbian, terminal, mouse

I am still working with different Os's, i am currently working with raspberry pi-os and i want to know how to change the mouse cursor using the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

> raspberry pi-os

If the OS in question is Raspbian, you can install the Xfce mouse configuration tool using `apt-get install xfce4-mouse-settings`

You can then unpack the desired icon into `$HOME/.icons` and then to change the cursor, edit (or create) the file `$HOME/.icons/default/index.theme` with:

```
[icon theme] 
Inherits=<theme-name>
```

With `<theme-name>` being the name of the theme.

([Source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/34041/101736))